# plyr indexing by columns gives NA

Tags: r, plyr

From http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/workshops/r-intro/lectures/6-advancedmanipulation.pdf
I get the bit of plyr code:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(baseball, .(year), function
      (df) mean(df[,6:9]))
```

Which yields the following:

```
    year V1
1   1871 NA
2   1872 NA
```

Plus the warning

> In mean.default(df[, 6:9]) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

This does work:

```
ddply(baseball, .(year), function(df) c(mean(df$ab), mean(df$h)))
```

but I'm trying to do a mean over 80 columns. I won't write out 80 means:(

What I'm really trying to do is:

```
ddply(myDF, c("dim1","dim2"), function(df)mean(df[,1:80))
```

I want to calculate the column mean for all combinations of 'dim1' & 'dim2'.
Ideas?

Comment: Seems like you might have a look at `colwise` or `numcolwise`

Comment: Replacing function(df)mean(df[,1:80) with colwise(mean)) worked like a charm. Thank you @Henrik!